# Transmit data from Excel to Access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

After going through online forums, I have developed some code to pull data from an X Access database and place within an excel, which is working successfully. From there, I want to take this data and place within another Access database. Think of the excel as the intermediary where, at some point (this is a project given by my boss), the excel will help produce calculations and that info will be taken to the other Access database. For the time being, I just want X Access data to be placed into Y Access sheet. I am having an issue with that placement. In Y Access database I want to head to the last row, insert a row, and place the data within. Sounds easy, but giving me a problem at the end in the DataPost() sub. For the below:

```
For i = 1 To oSelect.Rows.Count
    oRS.AddNew
For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
    oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
Next j
oRS.Update
Next i
oDB.Close
```

I am getting a Run-time error 3265 saying Item not found in this collection. I can walk through the code and see the data being selected, but when it gets to the end gives me that error.

I am using DAO connections, code below for the Pull and Post (problem) code. Online I see a lot of other options such as ADO, but I can't add outside of DAO connections I believe. I want to be able to provide the DataPull info as well so you can see my DAO logic I got from some others online.

The SQL Select is much longer, but was having error placing it within this forum so cut it down.

```
Sub DataPull()

    Const DbLoc As String = "C:\WIP\PullSample.accdb"
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet, recCount As Long
    Dim SQL As String, i As Double, n As Double, lr As Double, t As Double


    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
    Set wks2 = wkb.Worksheets(2)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)

    SQL = "SELECT [AA-AM].Dates, [AA-AM].[A US Equity]"
    SQL = SQL & "FROM [AA-AM] "
    SQL = SQL & "WHERE [AA-AM].Dates = Date() "

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    wks2.Range("B5").CopyFromRecordset rs
    wks2.Range("B5:GG5").Font.Name = "Garamond"
    wks2.Range("B5:GG5").Font.Size = 10

    wks2.Range("C5:GG5").Copy
    wks.Range("D6").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wks2 = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing


      End Sub

    Sub DataPost()

    Dim oSelect As Range, i As Long, j As Integer, sPath As String
    Dim lr as long
    Dim wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine, oDB As DAO.Database
    Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset
    Const DbLoc As String = "C:\WIP\ProjPullDB.accdb"

    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
    Set wks2 = wkb.Worksheets(2)
    Set oSelect = wks2.Range("B5:GG5")

    'wks2.Activate
    'oSelect.Copy

    Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
    Set oDB = oDAO.OpenDatabase(DbLoc)
    Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset("AA-AM")

    For i = 1 To oSelect.Rows.Count
        oRS.AddNew
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
        oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    oRS.Update
    Next i
    oDB.Close

End Sub
```

I expect to be able to place the `oSelect` data `wk2.Range("B5:GG5")` data into the Y Access database last row, but no luck.

Comment: Immediate suspicion is that your "post" database doesn't have enough columns to handle the data set you're trying to insert.  B5 to GG5 is a significant amount of columns.  Are you certain you have enough columns in the "AA-AM". Which specifc line of code does the error present itself? On the `oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)`  If that's the case, it may also be that you're hitting the end of the row in access before excel.  Fields is a 0 bounded array where 0 is the first item. This would cause you to start inserting on the second column in access form the first column in excel.

Comment: Try `oRS.Fields(j-1)` instead.

Comment: Hm interesting, so I did the j-1 and i am not longer getting the error. Thank you. But now I do not see that the data is being post within Recordset AA-AM..I search all over the database but cannot find the new data

Comment: Probably already gave this a shot, but if you have the table open already, hit F5 to refresh.  I've basically utilized your code to test and it worked fine on my end.  I'd suggest stepping through and debugging some of the code at the insert point. So step through up to the oRS.Fields(j) = and use something like `debug.print oSelect.Cells(i,j)` or hover over that portion to see if theres actively a value.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike that worked, I realized the next hour or so it was working, I just was not refreshing. Thanks so much. So now I am running into a bit more of a problem if I run it more than once in a day, let say if data is updated..first run through is perfect, updates based on today. The Access DB won't let me post more than one date so I have to manually go back in and delete those rows or else I get a run time error 3022. This is because date is primary key and I cannot change that, so cannot have duplicates. I am trying an IF function on the SQL code with no luck

Comment: formatting will look weird but here's the If I'm trying to develop SQL = "SELECT [AA-AM].Dates "
    SQL = SQL & "FROM [AA-AM] "
    SQL = SQL & "WHERE [AA-AM].Dates = Date()"
    
    If SQL = Date Then
    'blank here on purpose, do not want it do to anything
    Else
    
    For i = 1 To oSelect.Rows.Count
        rs.AddNew
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
        rs.Fields(j - 1) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    rs.Update
    Next i
    End If

Comment: Quick option to do this is adjust your `oDB.OpenRecordset("AA-AM")` to `oDB.OpenRecordset("AA-AM", dbOpenDynaset)`. This will open as a dynaset vs table type recordset and then we can do `oRS.FindFirst("date = " & date())`.  Then block your two For loops in a large if statement with the criteria `If oRS.NoMatch = True Then "update code"`

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
 For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
    oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
Next j
```

Fields is a zero based array so you are putting the data into the wrong field and when you get to the last column you attempt to access a field that isn't there. You want

```
For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
    oRS.Fields(j-1) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
Next j
```

Comment: Thanks Harassed! Got that to work with the help of you and Mike. As I said above to Mike, I am now running into a run time error of 3022 if I try to post more than once a day because date is primary key and I cannot change that, so cannot create duplicates. Hope that makes sense. I am trying an IF function on the SQL code with no luck

Comment: SQL = "SELECT [AA-AM].Dates "
    SQL = SQL & "FROM [AA-AM] "
    SQL = SQL & "WHERE [AA-AM].Dates = Date()"
    
    If SQL = Date Then
    'blank here on purpose, do not want it do to anything
    Else
    
    For i = 1 To oSelect.Rows.Count
        rs.AddNew
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
        rs.Fields(j - 1) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    rs.Update
    Next i
    End If